# qt5.0.1 The camera service is missing

Tags: c++, video, camera, media, qt5

I installed qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-msvc2010_32-x86-offline and qt-vs-addin-1.2.0-opensource in my win7 system,when i run the example of C:\QT5\5.0.1\msvc2010\examples\multimediawidgets\camera,it always tell me that "The camera service is missing". Can anybody tell me how to solve it? Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Camera support for WMF plugin will be implemented in a future release.
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28047